# Connect Dynamics CRM Online Accounts to Sharepoint Online

Tags: dynamics-crm

I need to create lists that have a column with the client name, which should be fetched in Accounts in Dynamics CRM Online, it will be an External Content Type column.
Can you help me with how to configure Sharepoint Online to search the information in the Dynamics CRM Online Accounts ??